# Laravel + Docker files are gone after restarting docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I am installing Laravel 10 with the help of docker, wsl and sail.

When I run the installation in one of the window disks (D:) I was having issues with Vite because every hot-reload took like around 20 seconds... after doing some digging I found out that this happen because I need to install Laravel within the Linux image...

I proceed to install within /mnt/wsl/my-project (this directory is given in wsl terminal) but if I close docker and open it again all the installed files are totally gone.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you install your laravel in wsl using curl? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos

Comment: I install a fresh laravel 10 app with sail enabled using the curl command. unless you run `sail down -v` to shutdown your container, the data should be persistent.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Docker Desktop. You may have misunderstood your sources. Ideally you would need to develop Laravel on WSL but you would need a separate WSL distribution to do that. If you attempt to use the one that comes with Docker Destktop you might have these issues because the Docker Desktop WSL distribution is meant to only support Docker Desktop. Install a separate WSL distribution and install your project on that and then enable WSL integration in your Docker Desktop

Answer (score 1):

You need to use volumes to persist the files in host machine.